# filter syslog messages rsyslog ubuntu

Tags: filter, ubuntu-16.04, syslog, rsyslog

Im trying to filter out all syslog messages except those who are defined in my config and then send the message to an external syslog server. 
I have Ubuntu 16.04 with rsyslog, and I have configured Nextcloud to log to the syslog daemon.

my message(from /var/syslog) I want to allow being sent to the external syslog server:

```
Jul 11 15:55:28 test-virtual-machine ownCloud[28466]: {files_antivirus} Infected file deleted. Eicar-Test-Signature File: files/eicar(3).com.ocTransferId993388412.part Acccount: admin
```

I have tried to modify the rsyslog.conf file (rest of the file is default):

```
nextcloud.*                         -/var/log/nextcloud.log

:msg, contains, "*Infected*" -/var/log/nextcloud3.log

nextcloud.* @remote-host:514
```

this is not working at all. Anyone have some inputs?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have the following that is currently working...

In /etc/rsyslog.d/60-my-filter.conf

:rawmsg,contains,"TAG" -/var/log/tag.log

My guess from the above, that you need to replace ":msg" with ":rawmsg", but I am no expert.  I would also try removing the spaces, or ':rawmsg,contains,"*Infected*" -/var/log/nextcloud3.log'

Also remove the nextcloud lines until you know you are getting the files formatted/filtered properly, and then try adding it back.

Hope this helps.